# I try to replace outliers with it's median but it doesn't work

Tags: python, data-analysis

I am trying to replace outliers in my data with it's median but am unable to perform the substitution:

```
data.boxplot("avg_glucose_level")[enter image description here][1]    


q1 = np.percentile(data["avg_glucose_level"], 25)
q2 = np.percentile(data["avg_glucose_level"], 50)
q3 = np.percentile(data["avg_glucose_level"], 75)    

print("q1:", q1)
print("q2:", q2)
print("q3:", q3)    

iqr = q3 - q1
print("iqr:", iqr)    

upper = q3 + (1.5 * iqr)
lower = q1 - (1.5 * iqr)    

print("upper:", upper)
print("lower:", lower)    

data["avg_glucose_level"] = np.where(
    data["avg_glucose_level"] > upper,
    q2,
    data["avg_glucose_level"]
    )

data.boxplot(column = "avg_glucose_level")
```

[enter image description here][2]

Comment: this looks right ... why do you think its not? ie what are you showing in that image?